# Changing text colour in navigation while page clicked not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to make a navigation bar with links.
I have it at the moment that upon hover, the colour of the text changes, and I'm trying to make it that when a navigation is clicked, it stays a colour while on that page, and then change the colour again when the next one is clicked.

My current script is:

```js
  $('span').click(function(){
   $('span').removeClass("active");
       $(this).addClass("active");
  });
```

```css
span.active {
color: #000000;
background-color:red;
}

#navshow1:hover, #navshow2:hover, #navshow3:hover {
  color: #4532e3;
  text-shadow: -0.06ex 0 #4532e3, 0.06ex 0 #4532e3;
}
```

```html
  <div class='navbarr'>
<li>
          <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <span class ='active'><a href="#home" class="current" id='navshow1'>home</a></span>
        <span><a href="#whatis" class="current" id='navshow2'>what is this site?</a></span>
      <span>  <a href="#test" class="current" id='navshow3'>test</a> </span>
      </li>
      </div>
```

I want exactly what is happening with the background colour, just for the text colour to stay dark purple while active. I don't know why its not working!!

Answer (score 2):

From an HTML perspective, you can't have an `li` without it being a child of an `ol` or `ul`. Additionally, the `span` elements are redundant because they are just inline elements like the `a` element is, so all you really need is the `a` elements (or the actual `li` elements that hold the `a` elements). Then, you wouldn't need any JavaScript at all as you would just use [`:focus` CSS pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus#:%7E:text=The%20%3Afocus%20CSS%20pseudo%2Dclass,the%20keyboard%27s%20%22tab%22%20key.&text=Note%3A%20This%20pseudo%2Dclass%20applies,to%20the%20focused%20element%20itself.).

```css
/* Correct way to use lists but display as horizontal nav bars */
ul{ list-style-type:none; padding:0; }
li{ display:inline-block; }

.current:hover {
  color: #4532e3;
  text-shadow: -0.06ex 0 #4532e3, 0.06ex 0 #4532e3;
}

.current:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Use <nav> instead of <div> for better semantics
     and make each link be its own list item. -->
<nav class='navbar'>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#home" class="current" id='navshow1'>home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#whatis" class="current" id='navshow2'>what is this site?</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#test" class="current" id='navshow3'>test</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Adding that css doesn't do anything

Comment: Yes, it will. After you've clicked on a link, that link will receive the focus and then the CSS will be applied and stay applied until you click on something else, which will then cause that element to receive the focus. Your code only triggers the CSS when you hover, but as soon as you move off the link, you aren't hovering anymore and the CSS is removed.

Comment: I'm so confused because the underline is staying there when I do this span.active {color: #4532e3; text-decoration: underline;} but the colour isnt. I can't figure out why

Comment: To be clear, all I see with regard to text color is that it gets bolder with a bit of a shadow. And my code retains that color after you move your mouse away from a clicked element.

Comment: Thanks, I tried. for some reason it's working when I do any other text css, like underline, background color etc. But when I try to change the actual text color to keep while it's on that page it doesn't work.

Comment: @user13948791 You most likely have a browser setting that is getting in the way. What do you get when you run my snippet right here? Does the background turn red and the text color turn white when you click on a link? And, does it stay that way until you click the next link?

Comment: @user13948791 Or, are you saying that you want the text color to stay even after you click off of the link?

Comment: No your first one was correct, I want the background colour and text colour to change when clicked and stay that way until the next one is clicked. The code snippet works exactly like that, and yeah I have run my html file and taken out all of the other code that could be affecting it and its still not working so maybe it is a browser issue

Comment: This fixed it.
li.active, .active .current {
    color: #4532e3;
   text-shadow: -0.06ex 0 #4532e3, 0.06ex 0 #4532e3;
    }

Answer (score -1):

```js
$('span').click(function() {
  $('span').removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
span.active>a {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#navshow1:hover,
#navshow2:hover,
#navshow3:hover {
  color: #4532e3;
  text-shadow: -0.06ex 0 #4532e3, 0.06ex 0 #4532e3;
}
```

```html
<div class='navbarr'>
  <li>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <span class='active'><a href="#home" class="current" id='navshow1'>home</a></span>
    <span><a href="#whatis" class="current" id='navshow2'>what is this site?</a></span>
    <span>  <a href="#test" class="current" id='navshow3'>test</a> </span>
  </li>
</div>
```